# Who is checking for questions that are tagged as duplicate

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, duplicate-questions

This is cool UX and I want to know who verifies questions marked as duplicate.

Comment: George Stocker does. Every single one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately everybody who uses the site.

Those with a reputation score of 3000 or more can vote to close, but anyone with at least 50 points can add a comment with a link to a duplicate and absolutely anyone can flag a post for moderator attention.

Then, when a question is closed other users can vote to reopen if they disagree with the original decision.